# FileNotFoundException exception in Android Studio core?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had just installed Android Studio 2.3.3 and created a new project.
Then the error occurred.
Here is the Event Log

> 2017/7/30
>
> 21:50 FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test
>   Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in C:/Program
>   Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/idea.jar
>
> 21:50 Gradle sync started
>
> 21:50 InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual
>   file: file://C:/Android/SDK/platforms/android-26/data/res;
>   original:182; found:-

And here are some pics.

[FileNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG7Dd.png)

[InvalidVirtualFileAccessException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ney.png)

I'm new to Android Studio.It'll be great if someone helps.

Comment: go to your SDK manager, and delete android-26 then reinstall it

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan But the exception still exists...

Comment: a small search showed that the issue could be solved with just going to (File>Invalidate caches/Restart...) will do the trick

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan Still exists....Anyway,thank you.

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan I was facing same issue and `File>Invalidate caches/Restart` fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the same problem I had. It was a new install of Android Studio.  I'm just trying to learn to build an app but couldn't even create a new class.

It turned out that I had installed the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine.  In my defense, there's a big green download button that says its for windows, it says nothing about 64/32 bit until you scroll waaaaay down the page.

I found the answer [here](http://android.2317887.n4.nabble.com/Error-Android-Studio-2-3-3-FileNotFoundException-Entry-fileTemplates-code-Google-Test-Fixture-td430490.html)

Steps to fix:
 1. uninstall android studio (but not the SDK)
 2. [download the 32 bit version](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) from the same page where I found the 64 bit one.
 3. Scroll down the page to find it.
 4. unzip the downloaded file and move it into the programs directory.
 5. launch android studion by opening the file \Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when trying to add C++ functionality, I think the fix will be similar too...

basicly I had to got to SDK Tools, tick the Show Packages, and then untick the Makec plugin

Comment: I've solved the issue by Sheree's answer and I think the problem occured because i try to install the 64-bit AS on my 32-bit system(And Google doesn't give a statement that you should download the correct version which depends on your system). Anyway,thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issye by adjusting BIOS Setup, when I adjusted the virtualization option.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.3.