# Error IDE android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle, ide

Please help me, I have error with android studio, I've been trying to find a solution to no avail as well, this error has been 2 weeks more since I first installed android studio, until now continue error, I install in ubuntu 32 bit, please help,Thanks.
[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSo95.png)

I use ubuntu 32 bit on machine 64 bit, i dont know android studio support 32 bit or no, in link android studio, android studio has only one version. I use DE gnome, to match the requested specifications of android studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with this exception in Android Studio core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400960/how-to-deal-with-this-exception-in-android-studio-core)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

and build tool version should be

> buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

Comment: This Not Worked.